# What is $e^{\scriptscriptstyle i^{e^{i^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers, recreational-mathematics

My friend asked me this question as a joke but I'm genuinely curious as to what the answer is. What is $$e^{\scriptscriptstyle i^{e^{i^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$$?

My attempt:

I first set $z$ equal to $e^{\scriptscriptstyle i^{e^{i^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$.

$z=e^{\scriptscriptstyle i^{e^{i^{.^{.^{.}}}}}}$

$z=e^{\scriptscriptstyle i^z}$

$z=e^{iz}$

I then used the Euler's Identity $e^{i\pi}=-1$ to find that $e^i=(-1)^\frac{1}{\pi}$

$z=(-1)^{\frac{z}{\pi}}$

$z=i^{\frac{2z}{\pi}}$

I really don't know what to do at this point. Is this even solvable? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $$e^{i^z} \neq (e^i)^z$$

Comment: @N.S. How do I simplify $e^{\scriptscriptstyle i^z}$ then? Do I take the $z$th root and the $i$th root on both sides?

Comment: Why do you think $e^{i^z}$ can be simplified? Anyway, $i^z$ is multivalued in general, so you have to specify one of the infinitely many branches. For each occurrence of $i^z$ actually.

Comment: Even if one could solve $z=e^{i^z}$, that would only give the value of the original expression if that value existed—it wouldn't prove that it existed. Do you have any reason to think that the value exists—that is, that the finite versions of the expression tend to a limit?

Comment: From Wolfram Alpha, x ≈ -0.967506 - 0.604909 i... or x ≈ 0.935118 + 0.476098 i...

Comment: Old McDonald had a farm $e^{i^{e^{i^{e^{i^{.^{.^{}}}}}}}}$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen. Thanks for pointing out my mistake ! Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Defining
$$f_1=e^i \qquad \text{and} \qquad f_n=e^{i^{f_{n-1}}}$$ I do not knwow if we could find a closed form (I cannot !) but we can compute and get the following results (from a CAS, for sure)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & f_n \\
 10 & 0.8998004087100258109381994\,+\,0.5136686926540903864487995 \,i \\
 20 & 0.9391912394435662668247780\,+\,0.4748699491196762314648294 \,i \\
 30 & 0.9347741922806840376959014\,+\,0.4760068686818573570569700 \,i \\
 40 & 0.9351388632350392268316969\,+\,0.4761191810522562585293457 \,i \\
 50 & 0.9351177256059159924314937\,+\,0.4760952592226891475767457 \,i \\
 60 & 0.9351181910018841373863410\,+\,0.4760978887346746827736599 \,i \\
 70 & 0.9351182724741915050552121\,+\,0.4760976807368583340653701 \,i \\
 80 & 0.9351182575862408277286842\,+\,0.4760976920304049178539746 \,i \\
 90 & 0.9351182591415594580823332\,+\,0.4760976918736317087490291 \,i \\
 100 & 0.9351182590237006433692816\,+\,0.4760976918169832534042577 \,i \\
 110 & 0.9351182590296427005539796\,+\,0.4760976918261676061832348 \,i \\
 120 & 0.9351182590296191471242818\,+\,0.4760976918252528368153811 \,i
\end{array}
\right)$$

They stabilize quite fast. The problem is that the last numbers are not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

Comment: But this doesn’t seem to be the sequence of exponentiations indicated in the notation.

Comment: @KevinCarlson. Am I wrong ? Being almost blind, I may misread (which happens to me quite often). Would you clarify for me ? Thanks and cheers :-(

Comment: As pointed out by the comments, exponentiation is evaluated top down, as doing it bottom up is trivial: $a^{b^c}=a^{(b^c)}\ne(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$.

Comment: Claude, the recurrence should be $f_n=e^{i^{f_{n-1}}}$.

Comment: So is there no way to find an exact answer to the expression(just an approximation)?